# understanding docker container cpu usages

Tags: docker, microservices

`docker stats` shows that the cpu usage to be very high. But `top` command out shows that 88.3% cpu is not being used. Inside the container is a java service httpthrift service.

```
docker stats :
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT    MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
8a0488xxxx5        540.9%             41.99 GiB / 44 GiB   95.43%              0 B / 0 B           0 B / 35.2 MB       286
```

top output :

```
top - 07:56:58 up 2 days, 22:29,  0 users,  load average: 2.88, 3.01, 3.05
Tasks:  13 total,   1 running,  12 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.2 us,  2.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.9 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  65959920 total, 47983628 used, 17976292 free,   357632 buffers
KiB Swap:  7999484 total,        0 used,  7999484 free.  2788868 cached Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                               
  8823 root      20   0 58.950g 0.041t  21080 S 540.9 66.5  16716:32 java
```

How to reduce the cpu usage and bring it under 100%?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [top man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html):

> When operating in Solaris mode (`I' toggled Off), a task's cpu usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs.  After issuing this command, you'll be told the new state of this toggle.

So by pressing the key `I` when using top in interactive mode, you will switch to the Solaris mode and the CPU usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs (or cores).

P.S.: This option is not available on all versions of top.